# IIS 7 HTTP Error 401.3 on one file but ok on another

Tags: iis, iis-7, acl, http-status-code-401

I have 2 file in an IIS virtual directory
b1.html  // shows up ok when I browse to
 
   `http://localhost/bob/bs2/b1.html`
b2.html  // gives 401.3 error when I browse to 
   `http://localhost/bob/bs2/b2.html`
contents of both files are the same "bob"

running icsacl `b1.html` gives:

b1.html BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
        BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files


running `icsacl b2.html` gives:

b2.html BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
        BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files


so, same results on both files
I copied b1.html to good.html -> browses ok
i copied b2.html to bad.html -> 401.3 error as before

I edited both files and still, same result

if both files have the same content and the same acl info how can they be different?

Comment: ran attrib on both and got "A"

Comment: I just copied the whole dir to a network drive and the 2 bad files (b1.html and bad.html) reported "The specified file could nto be encrypted" where the others did not have any warnings.